# Puppet: why my manifest won't install Vsftpd on Centos machines?

Tags: puppet

This is my manifest,I'm puppet newbie

```
class vsftpd {
        if $::operatingsystem == 'CentOS' {
                package { "vsftpd":
                        ensure => installed
                }
        }
}
node 'puppet.domain.example' {
        include vsftpd
}
node 'centos2.domain.example' {
        include vsftpd
}
node 'centos3.domain.example' {
        include vsftpd
}
```

On master

```
puppet apply manifest.pp
```

No error.

On node centos2

```
puppet agent
```

No error

And even on centos2...

```
rpm -qa|grep -i vsftp
```

Not installed :(

On master vsftp is installed.
What's wrong?

edit1: I also tried

```
puppet agent -t
```

But no way

Comment: You're misunderstanding quite a lot - there is no reason to run puppet apply manifest.pp on the master - that doesn't make sense - and the command from the agent is usually puppet agent -t. You'll probably need to start by doing a Puppet tutorial.

Comment: I have tried also puppet -t,but don't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found: manifests were in wrong dir. Must be on dir

```
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests
```